# Is iterating over an array with a for loop a thread safe operation in C# ? What about iterating an IEnumerable<T> with a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Based on my understanding, given a C# array, the act of iterating over the array concurrently from multiple threads **is** a thread safe operation.

By *iterating over the array* I mean reading all the positions inside the array by means of a **plain old `for` loop**. Each thread is simply reading the content of a memory location inside the array, no one is writing anything so all the threads read the same thing in a consistent manner.

This is a piece of code doing what I wrote above:

```
public class UselessService 
{
   private static readonly string[] Names = new [] { "bob", "alice" };

   public List<int> DoSomethingUseless()
   {
      var temp = new List<int>();

      for (int i = 0; i < Names.Length; i++) 
      {
        temp.Add(Names[i].Length * 2);
      }

      return temp;
   }
}
```

So, my understanding is that the method `DoSomethingUseless` **is thread safe** and that **there is no need** to replace the `string[]` with a thread safe type (like `ImmutableArray<string>` for instance).

Am I correct ?

Now let's suppose that we have an instance of `IEnumerable<T>`. We don't know what the underlying object is, we just know that we have an object implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, so we are able to iterate over it by using the `foreach` loop.

Based on my understanding, in this scenario there is **no** guarantee that iterating over this object from multiple threads concurrently is a thread safe operation. Put another way, it is entirely possible that iterating over the `IEnumerable<T>` instance from different threads at the same time breaks the internal state of the object, so that it becomes corrupted.

Am I correct on this point ?

What about the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation of the `Array` class ? Is it thread safe ?

Put another way, is the following code thread safe ? (this is exactly the same code as above, but now the array is iterated by using a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop)

```
public class UselessService 
{
   private static readonly string[] Names = new [] { "bob", "alice" };

   public List<int> DoSomethingUseless()
   {
      var temp = new List<int>();

      foreach (var name in Names) 
      {
        temp.Add(name.Length * 2);
      }

      return temp;
   }
}
```

Is there any reference stating which `IEnumerable<T>` implementations in the .NET base class library are 
actually thread safe ?

Comment: No, itterating over a array is not thread save. Asume nothing is thread save, until you made it that way or it says so explicitly.

If you need to created thread safety, that in practice means the lock statement wrapping all access to the instance (and all copies of it's reference). Do keep the pattern of locking onto a dedicated, private object in mind. I would bet you real money, using lock is all that "ThreadSave" code does use it too.

Comment: foreach is actually a bit worse. See, foreach does not work with Collections - it only work with Enumerators. Now creating a Enumerator form a Collection is a implicit operation that just happens, so you never notice until you run into a the limits. One of them is "the underlying collection is not allowed to change. If it does, the Enumerators must become invalid".

Comment: Regardless of the for loops, you also have to consider a variable going "stale" (having received a update on another thread or CPU cache, that has not yet propagated to where you code is reading from). But Afaik locking and/or the volatile keyword take care of that.

Comment: @Christopher: Re: your first comment: in Enrico's scenario where an array is being *only read*, and neither the storage of the array reference nor the elements of the array are being mutated, a multiple-readers scenario should be safe without additional barriers.

Comment: @Christopher *"No, itterating over a array is not thread save."* - Iterating over an array (i.e. [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array)) will be thread safe as long as all threads are only reading it. Same with `List<T>`, and probably every other Microsoft-written collection. But it is possible to make your own `IEnumerable` that does non-thread safe things in the enumerator. Therefore, it is not a guarantee that everything that implements `IEnumerable` will be thread safe.

Comment: @Christopher: Re: your second comment: no, `foreach` works with more than just enumerators. The compiler is smart enough to know that if it has static type information indicating that the collection is an array, it skips generating the enumerator and just accesses the array directly like it was a `for` loop. Similarly, if the collection supports a *custom* implementation of `GetEnumerator`, that implementation is used instead of calling `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`.  The notion that `foreach` only traffics in `IEnumerable/IEnumerator` is false.

Comment: @Christopher: Re: your third comment: be careful. Though there may be such a thing as "stale", the notion that there is therefore also such a thing as "fresh" is not accurate. `volatile` does not guarantee that you get the freshest possible update to a variable because *C# allows different threads to observe different orderings of reads and writes, and therefore the notion of "freshest" is not globally defined*. Instead of reasoning about freshness, reason about what *restrictions* `volatile` places on how writes can be re-ordered.

Comment: @EnricoMassone: I am not attempting to answer any of your questions but I do note that your questions indicate that you want to do something very risky, namely, write a low-lock or no-lock solution that shares memory across threads.  I would not attempt to do so except in cases where there really was no other choice that met my performance goals, and in cases where I felt confident to thoroughly and accurately analyze all the possible re-orderings of all the reads and writes in the program. Since you're asking these questions, I think you feel less confident than I would be comfortable with.

Comment: @EricLippert not really. I wrote a piece of code having a structure quite similar to the `UselessService` of my example. After that I found myself asking questions such as "do I need locking here ?" and "can I safely register this class as a singleton on my container ?". I know that avoiding locks and sharing state can really hurt myself, that's why I'm asking and trying to understand the hard bits. Anyway, I really appreciate your warning, I do understand what you mean. Lock free is rarely a good idea, unless you are an expert and you need very high performace (that's not my case, really)

Comment: @Rufus Given that the answer to the linked question is wrong, it seems like a really bad idea to use it as a duplicate answer (and yes I've written IEnumerables that were not thread safe to access)

Comment: @EricLippert: Someone had closed the thread, so I was not able to write a proper answer. Had to more or less squeze it into comments. "in Enrico's scenario where an array is being only read [...] a multiple-readers scenario should be safe without additional barriers." The issue with Multitasking, Thread safety and race conditions is that we need to see the full code, to give any explicit advice. If there is a reader, there will be a writer. And if there is a writer, there will be a reader. And those two need to avoid colissions equally to maintain thread safety.

Comment: @EricLippert I was not aware foreach could default to a simple for. Every time we had someone learn about Enumerators, it was because they used them in a loop and learned about the "no changes" rule the hard way. | Even knowing that there are exceptions, I do not consider them worth mentioning. As a compiler/JiT feature the are not realiable enough to rely on | I wanted to write that is ia plus and minus case. On the plus side, it really protects you from race conditions because on most it will invalidate. Indeed we recently had someone saved by just this part. The minus si what I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is iterating over an array with a for loop a thread safe operation in C# ?**

If you're strictly talking about **reading from multiple threads**, that will be thread safe for `Array` and `List<T>` and just about every collection written by Microsoft, regardless of if you're using a `for` or `foreach` loop. Especially in the example you have:

```
var temp = new List<int>();

foreach (var name in Names)
{
  temp.Add(name.Length * 2);
}
```

You can do that across as many threads as you want. They'll all read the same values from `Names` happily.

**If you write to it from another thread** (this wasn't your question, but it's worth noting)

Iterating over an `Array` or `List<T>` with a `for` loop, it'll just keep reading, and it'll happily read the changed values as you come across them.

Iterating with a `foreach` loop, then it depends on the implementation. If a value in an `Array` changes part way through a `foreach` loop, it will just keep enumerating and give you the changed values.

With `List<T>`, it depends what you consider "thread safe". If you are more concerned with reading accurate data, then it kind of is "safe" since it will throw an exception mid-enumeration and tell you that the collection changed. But if you consider throwing an exception to be not safe, then it's not safe.

But it's worth noting that this is a design decision in `List<T>`, [there is code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1173) that explicitly looks for changes and throws an exception. Design decisions brings us to the next point:

**Can we assume that *every* collection that implements `IEnumerable` is safe to read across multiple threads?**

In *most cases* it will be, but thread-safe reading is not guaranteed. The reason is because every `IEnumerable` requires an implementation of [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator), which decides how to traverse the items in the collection. And just like any class, you can do *anything you want* in there, including non-thread-safe things like:

- Using static variables
- Using a shared cache for reading values
- Not making any effort to handle cases where the collection changes mid-enumeration
- etc.

You could even do something weird like make [`GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator) return the same instance of your enumerator every time its called. That could really make for some unpredictable results.

I consider something to not be thread safe if it can result in unpredictable results. Any of those things could cause unpredictable results.

You can see [the source code for the `Enumerator` that `List<T>` uses](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140), so you can see that it doesn't do any of that weird stuff, which tells you that enumerating `List<T>` from multiple threads is safe.

Comment: so basically if someone gives you an instance of IEnumerable and the **only** thing that you know about it is that it implements IEnumerable, then **it is not safe** to enumerate that object from different threads. Otherwise, if you have an instance of a BCL class, say an instance of List<string>, you can safely enumerate the object from multiple threads (even if the List<string> type itself is not thread safe in all its members, you can be sure that it's implementation of the IEnumerable interface is thread safe).

Comment: all the discussion about the safety of concurrent enumerations of BCL collections is based on an assumption: we can read the source code provided by microsoft and as of today we don't know any example of BCL class which is not thread safe with regard to concurrent enumeration. We are basically relying on an implementation detail. Unless something is not explicitly documented, doing assumption is not the safest option. So, the safest choice is probably avoiding troubles and using something like an ImmutableArray<string>, which we know for sure being thread safe because of its immutability.

Comment: *"the safest choice is probably avoiding troubles and using something like an ImmutableArray<string>"* - If you have control over the type of the collection, and you know that you will only be reading across threads, then `List<T>` or `Array` is just as safe as `ImmutableArray<string>`, since we can prove those are thread safe to read. I would only look into other options if you plan on reading *and writing* across multiple threads. You could use an appropriate collection from [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent).

Answer (score 1):

To assert that your code is thread-safe means that we must take your words for granted that there is no code inside the `UselessService` that will try to replace concurrently the contents of the `Names` array with something like `"tom" and "jerry"` or (more sinister) `null and null`. On the other hand using an [`ImmutableArray<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray) would **guarantee** that the code is thread-safe, and everybody could be assured about that just by looking the type of the static readonly field, without having to inspect carefully the rest of the code.

You may find interesting these comments from the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e99ec129cfd594d53f4390bf97d1d736cff6f860/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray_1.Minimal.cs#L16) of the `ImmutableArray<T>`, regarding some implementation details of this struct:

> A readonly array with O(1) indexable lookup time.
>
> This type has a documented contract of being exactly one reference-type field in size. Our own `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableInterlocked` class depends on it, as well as others externally.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTICE FOR MAINTAINERS AND REVIEWERS:
>
> This type should be thread-safe. As a struct, it cannot protect its own fields from being changed from one thread while its members are executing on other threads because structs can change *in place* simply by reassigning the field containing this struct. Therefore it is extremely important that **Every member should only dereference `this` ONCE.** If a member needs to reference the array field, that counts as a dereference of `this`. Calling other instance members (properties or methods) also counts as dereferencing `this`. Any member that needs to use `this` more than once must instead assign `this` to a local variable and use that for the rest of the code instead. This effectively copies the one field in the struct to a local variable so that it is insulated from other threads.